# disable cursor blinking in terminal-vim

Tags: terminal, cursor

I thought this would be a 10 second google search, but no. I found a bazillion sources how to disable cursor blinking in GVim. But I would like to disable it in terminal vim. My terminal cursor is set to no-blink globally already. It does not blink in any shell program. But it does in vim. How can I turn this off?

Comment: Hi, does setting this: `let &t_EI .= "\<Esc>[2 q"` solves your problem?

Comment: No. But I noticed it happens when I run `echo -e "\033c\e[3J"` in the terminal inside vim (`:terminal`). I have that in an alias for clearing the screen (for real). It does not happen when I run that in my normal terminal.

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you using? And to be clear, you are talking about Vim blinking the cursor in the terminal buffer only (and not anywhere else)?

Comment: no, it blinks in all buffers. It just gets triggered when entering said command in the terminal buffer. I am using guake.

Comment: This question was [answered on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12440360/7096763). Long story short: it's a terminal setting, you have to configure the terminal on your machine.